# Preciso de ajuda com JQuery e/ou JS para Drop Down Menu dependente

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, dropdown

Estou desenvolvendo um programa onde tem um menu drop down contento os valores Mensal, Semanal ou Diário que são a periodicidade em que uma tarefa do sistema deve ser executada. 
Ai tem um segundo menu drop down que deve conter opções de acordo com o que foi escolhido no primeiro. Se for mensal, exibe de 0 a 31, semanal exibe de domingo a sábado e diário é vazio.

Eu havia feito isso com divs, mas ao fazer alterações (mesmo usando uma função     remove()     no JS para limpar a lista) ele apenas estava conseguindo alterar de semanal para mensal, quando o contrário era feito, o dia da semana não era alterado de forma alguma, mesmo os valores do drop down estando corretos.

Ai meu chefe sugeriu fazer de uma outra forma que sequer está funcionando que é o que está abaixo. Alguém tem sugestões ou pode me apontar os erros por favor?

O Script e o HTML embaixo

```js
<style type="text/css" media="all">
@import url("http://www.'.$_SESSION['p_url'].'css/cs_style_frm.css");
</style>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
       $("#tipoPeriodo").change(function() {
       $( "option", "#diaPeriodo" ).remove()
       if ($(this).val() == "m") {
          for (var i=1; i<=31; i++){
            $(#diaPeriodo).html = ("<option value="+i+">+i+<option>");
          }
       } 
       if ($(this).val() == "s"){
          $("#diaPeriodo").html("<option value="1">Segunda-feira</option>"); 
          $("#diaPeriodo").html("<option value="2">Terça-feira</option>"); 
          $("#diaPeriodo").html("<option value="3">Quarta-feira</option>"); 
          $("#diaPeriodo").html("<option value="4">Quinta-feira</option>"); 
          $("#diaPeriodo").html("<option value="5">Sexta-feira</option>"); 
          $("#diaPeriodo").html("<option value="6">Sábado</option>"); 
          $("#diaPeriodo").html("<option value="7">Domingo</option>"); 
       } 
       if ($(this).val == "d"){
          $("#diaPeriodo").html("<option value="0"> </option>"); 
       }    
    });
});
</script>'
```

```html
<label>Dia de Execução <label><br />
<select style="width:150px;" id="diaPeriodo" name="diaPeriodo"></select><br />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente você cometeu alguns erros básicos de javascript, seguem eles abaixo:

```
$( "option", "#diaPeriodo" ).remove()  // foi substituido por $("#diaPeriodo").empty();
```

---

```
$(#diaPeriodo).html = ("<option value="+i+">+i+<option>"); 
// foi substituido por $("#diaPeriodo").append('<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>');
// Pois o mesmo não funcionaria visto que as concatenações estavam erradas
```

---

O Bloco:

```
$("#diaPeriodo").html("<option value="1">Segunda-feira</option>"); 
$("#diaPeriodo").html("<option value="2">Terça-feira</option>"); 
$("#diaPeriodo").html("<option value="3">Quarta-feira</option>"); 
$("#diaPeriodo").html("<option value="4">Quinta-feira</option>"); 
$("#diaPeriodo").html("<option value="5">Sexta-feira</option>"); 
$("#diaPeriodo").html("<option value="6">Sábado</option>"); 
$("#diaPeriodo").html("<option value="7">Domingo</option>");
```

estava errado pois quando você utilizou as aspas duplas `"` para agrupar o value você fechou o inicio da string, substitui as aspas duplas iniciais por aspas simples `'` para funcionar vide exemplo abaixo:

```
$("#diaPeriodo").append('<option value="1">Segunda-feira</option>');
$("#diaPeriodo").append('<option value="2">Terça-feira</option>');
$("#diaPeriodo").append('<option value="3">Quarta-feira</option>');
$("#diaPeriodo").append('<option value="4">Quinta-feira</option>');
$("#diaPeriodo").append('<option value="5">Sexta-feira</option>');
$("#diaPeriodo").append('<option value="6">Sábado</option>');
$("#diaPeriodo").append('<option value=7">Domingo</option>');
```

---

```
if ($(this).val == "d"){ // Faltou o os parenteses val() é uma function
```

---

Em todas as vezes que você tentou adicionar uma option na select você utilizou o `$.html` só que o respectivo apaga o conteúdo anterior portanto somente o ultimo registro ficaria nas opções, substitui os `$.html` por `$.append` que adiciona novos elementos na seleção mantendo os anteriores.

---

Segue abaixo um exemplo funcional do que você pretendia fazer:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $("#tipoPeriodo").change(function() {

    $("#diaPeriodo").empty();

    if ($(this).val() == "m") {
      for (var i = 1; i <= 31; i++) {
        $("#diaPeriodo").append('<option value="' + i + '">' + i + '</option>');
      }
    }

    if ($(this).val() == "s") {
      $("#diaPeriodo").append('<option value="1">Segunda-feira</option>');
      $("#diaPeriodo").append('<option value="2">Terça-feira</option>');
      $("#diaPeriodo").append('<option value="3">Quarta-feira</option>');
      $("#diaPeriodo").append('<option value="4">Quinta-feira</option>');
      $("#diaPeriodo").append('<option value="5">Sexta-feira</option>');
      $("#diaPeriodo").append('<option value="6">Sábado</option>');
      $("#diaPeriodo").append('<option value=7">Domingo</option>');
    }

    if ($(this).val() == "d") {
      $("#diaPeriodo").append('<option value="0">Será executado diariamente...</option>');
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Periodicidade da Execução
</label>
<select style="width:200px;" id="tipoPeriodo" name="tipoPeriodo">
  <option>Selecione...</option>
  <option value="m">Mensalmente</option>
  <option value="s">Semanalmente</option>
  <option value="d">Diariamente</option>
</select>
<br />
<label>Intervalo de Execução
</label>
<select style="width:200px;" id="diaPeriodo" name="diaPeriodo">
</select>
```

Comment: Era exatamente isso. Muito obrigada.